How difficult is it to switch from non-tenure to tenure track in Japan?
There’s an opening for assistant and associate professorship in non-tenure track of maximum of 5 years. I’m currently living in Europe and my Japanese is basic level.
I was wondering how difficult it is, or even possible, to apply for a tenure track while in non-tenure track in Japan?
It’s a big risk & investment to move to another continent but I’m willing to take the risk.

It would also be advisable to investigate whether Japanese and non-Japanese employees are treated equally, which probably depends on the institution. In the past, these two groups were often not treated equally. See https://www.debito.org/univquestions.html.  Things have improved to some extent in the last 25 years, but I don't know much and you should definitely investigate.

I think it depends on your particular organization. Say, at my university there are no such restrictions, so you can freely apply, and perhaps it's a good thing they already know you  personally. At least from what I have seen, "non-tenure track" usually means simply that you are funded by a fixed-time grant that is not going to be prolonged.

Generally speaking, it is not easy to have a tenured position in Japan, especially at a good university. However to discuss details maybe you want to add your long-term goals, your field, etc, because without that the discussion is very general.

In my experience and from what I have seen, it is very difficult to secure a tenure-track position in Japan. This challenge exists even for Japanese nationals and is even more pronounced for foreigners.
Most non-tenure positions that differ from a typical post-doctoral role often have titles like "Program-Specific Assistant Professor" (the exact title depends on the university). However, in many cases, the responsibilities are similar to those of a post-doc, with possibly a slightly higher salary.
These positions are typically tied to specific projects funded for about 3-5 years. If you have the necessary skills, securing such a position as a foreigner is not overly difficult. I have often seen researchers start as post-docs and then get promoted to roles like "Program-Specific Assistant Professor" after a few years. By law, you can claim a permanent academic position at a university or research center after 10 years. However, this often means that contracts are not extended beyond 6 or 7 years due to funding uncertainties.
Switching to a tenure-track position is challenging for two main reasons:
Limited Availability: There are only a limited number of tenure-track positions available.
Language Requirements: Teaching is predominantly conducted in Japanese, and non-Japanese classes are often handled by personnel in non-tenure track positions. Therefore, becoming fluent in Japanese is crucial.
I recommend exploring the job listings on JREC-IN to understand the requirements for tenure-track positions.
Additionally, these Nature articles provide a good overview of the postdoc situation in Japan:

‘I feel disposable’: Thousands of scientists’ jobs at risk in Japan
Freeing up Japan’s PhD potential

